# how can achive jquery accordion for nested ul li tags...?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to display a jQuery accordion for my nested `<ul>` `<li>` tags...

I found this site to display accordion: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

But unfortunately, it's using `<h3>` tags as headers.

In my actual code, I just had only `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, I tried , but I am unable to understand what function to write to get that.

My code style looks similar as:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea
      <ul>
      <li>China</li>
      <li>Africa</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Prepend four spaces to each line (or select your code and hit `Ctrl+K`, or use the Code Sample `{}` toolbar button) to format some of your content as code.

Comment: Thanks I did, could you please tell me how can i achive for my prob..?

Comment: That's hard to say, accordions are inherently flat (headers and panes, one header per pane), they do not have a nested structure. Maybe you want nested accordions (though it may not be a good thing from a user experience standpoint)? Can you give us an idea of the result you're looking for?

Comment: hi,  i found this link as per my requirement, BUT I didnt understood, how to write code for what he explains.. here is that link: http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html

Comment: Read the _Getting started:_ section on the page that you referenced.  He explains how to use the plugin there, with examples.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to structure your document like in the examples.
jQuery is searching a header with an anchor, followed by a div block, and so on ...

Example:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

So, you have to use the markup of jQuery, otherwise jQuery will not recognize your content.
Another problem of your `<ul>` list is, that jQuery doesn't know which part is the header and which part is the content.

At this point you have several options:

- You can find the corresponding lines of code in jQuery and edit them (not recommended)
- You can write your own accordion (based on the original)
- (If you really want your `<ul>` list) You can exchange the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags at runtime with the corresponding "jQuery tags"
- Use the markup of jQuery (recommended)

Best regards

Comment: hey, thanks for your brief answer.. Now my reqauirement is:  I should use an accordion to my ul li tags.. 

atleast if I can achive any one from here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu.htm

Comment: So, there is NO way to achive Accordion for ul li tags..?

Comment: I briefly looked at the jQuery code. Good news, you don't have to use `<h3>` tags, any block tag does the job. However, with the current implementation you cannot use `<li>` tags.

Comment: (ad. ul li tags) At least it is not possible with jQuery Accordion. You can rewrite the jQuery Accordion to accomplish your goal, or exchange the ul li tags with jQuery at runtime to comply with the markup.

Comment: Block tags..? Actually In my code, I have only ul li tags, i cannot modify it either.. At the end, i should achive this type of : http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/  no matters whether I use accordion or something other else, my output should be similar to that link.. so, is there any other way..?

Comment: Hey can YOU also show me how to put CSS using this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ for your code..? Iam new to this jquery, and I need this css bit urgent.. it takes time for me o udnerstnd this jquery..